# can we use custom service application for FAST in sharepoint 2010 for content to publish?

Tags: service-applications

I have a scenario where i need to crete custom sharepoint service application and need to use FQL for getting the content from FAST and send the data to various farms or users through Email or someother process .Will it be possible to use custom sharepoint service application for FAST to get the content?

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt that that is your scenarion. What you describe, is a solution for a specific problem and you are not sure that it is going to work. So my question for you:

what is your problem?
Do you need to get always the same content? Or is it a static query that is always the same? Will you need to expose content to other applications than sharepoint in the future? What about seciurity trimming?

your first start will be to consume the web service that is tied to your site collection, to query your data by fql.

A custom service application is always possible, but I really doubt the need for it. Aside from that: custom service applications are a bit complex and do cost a lot of work, as you also need to implment UI, authorization etc. for it. maybe a small,reusable library will be sufficient for you.

Comment: I need to implement service application a 24x7 timer job associated to it so that the conetnt is placed to various regions but in the same time (7am in usa should be the same 7am in india).But my query is is that possible to grab the data from the fast using fql by service application.It is not a static query and need to expose content to others too.Please help me out with it.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks Bas Lijten for your reply.I will elaborate our scenario .Actually we have content coming from different lists but we have fast search in the middle and service application at the end .So the custom service application will be getting the data from the fast indexing and its hould be automated(custom service application) using timerjob which should run 24X7 
So how can i start with actually i have created a service aplication but how to implement timer job to make it automated an drun 24X7?Please need suggestions.Thanks .